# Вставка рекламы admob в приложение с Youtube API?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, в том году запретили использовать youtube API в приложениях вместе с монетизацией, не пропускают такие приложения на google play. Может есть какой нибудь выход, как обойти это и все таки добавить рекламу в приложения с youtube API?